# Limiting the scope of JQuery UI sortable() on nested lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have created a nested list of the form...

```
<ol>
    <li>Group One
        <ol>
            <li>Item1 in group one</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Group Two
        <ol>
            <li>Item1 in group two</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>External Item 1</li>
    <li>External Item 2</li>
</ol>
```

Using Jquery UI I have made the lists sortable so for example External Item 1 could be nested in Group One, and the external items and groups can be sorted together in any order.
What I want to prevent is the user being able to nest a group  inside another group, while still allowing it to be dragged to different positions in the list. It shouldn't make any difference, but the list is being generated in razor by an external model that holds collections of groups. (An external item is stored as a member of a group which has an empty GUID for an id)

Simply put, how do I tell a specific class of `<li>` to not ever position itself in a child list Or how do i tell the child list to refuse certain items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally solved (or so it seems) that riddle. )) The trick is to assign a custom `.stop` event handler, in which check two conditions: whether the moved element was a group, and whether it's new position is in outer space. It looks like that:

```
$('ol').sortable({
  // to connect inner lists and outer list between themselves 
  connectWith: ".sortable",

  // to intercept a movement  
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.item.children('ol').length         // if it's a group...
        && ! ui.item.parent('.outer').length) // but moved within another group
    {
        $(this).sortable('cancel');           // cancel the sorting!
    }
}});
```

Here's the [proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/w6AxF/). Inner checks might be made even more simple with correct usage of identifiers (in jsfiddle they're used only for debugging purposes).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly. It isn't possible to create nested list entries. You can only rearrange the items.

Answer (score 0):

Using the containment option of sortable with a value of "parent" should accomplish this.

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({ containment: 'parent' });
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-containment

http://jsfiddle.net/bstakes/kQDmZ/

Comment: Thank you for trying, but i need to be able to get the child elements out of the groups and vice versa